# How to convert all pdf files in a directory/folder to image python 3?

Tags: python, image, pdf

How to convert all pdf files in a directory/folder to image python 3? is there any alternative?

while running this code i m getting an error like

> pdf2image.exceptions.PDFPageCountError: Unable to get page count.
>   Syntax Warning : May not be a PDF file (continuing anyway) Syntax
>   Error: Couldn't find trailer dictionary Syntax Error: Couldn't find
>   trailer dictionary Syntax Error: Couldn't read xref table

I dono why please someone help me

```
from pdf2image import convert_from_path
import glob,os
import os, subprocess

pdf_dir = r"C:\\Users\\xxx\\Desktop\\folder1\\folder2\\"
os.chdir(pdf_dir)

for pdf_file in os.listdir(pdf_dir):
    pages = convert_from_path(pdf_file, 500)
    for page in pages:
        page.save(pdf_file[:-4] +".jpg", 'JPEG')
```

Comment: What is the error now ?

Comment: please see again

Comment: is there any alternative?

Comment: are you sure you have only valid pdf files in the `pdf_dir`? (no sub directories, no invalid pdf files)

Comment: yes@ najjarammar

Comment: this error occurred to me when I tried os.listdir() and os.path.abspath() but using glob module solved the problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you've both JPG and PDF in the same directory. To iterate over only PDF files:

```
from pdf2image import convert_from_path
import glob,os
import os, subprocess

pdf_dir = r"C:\\Users\\xxx\\Desktop\\folder1\\folder2\\"
os.chdir(pdf_dir)

for pdf_file in glob.glob(os.path.join(pdf_dir, "*.pdf")):
    pages = convert_from_path(pdf_file, 500)
    for page in pages:
        page.save(pdf_file[:-4] +".jpg", 'JPEG')
```

Comment: change path.dir to path_dir

Comment: Should be `pdf_dir` instead.